# How to build the query "SELECT id, category IS NOT NULL AND category IN (1, 2) AS my_category FROM my_table" in knex

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to build a complex query using knex.js, where in the select part I want to select some fields as boolean if they have one of the specific values. The simplified version of the query itself is as in the title of the question like following:

```sql
SELECT 
    "ID", 
    "Category" IS NOT NULL AND "Category" IN (1, 2) AS "My_Category" 
FROM "My_Table";
```

How could I write it in knex.js? What I have know is that:

```js
knex.select({ID: 'My_Table.ID', My_Category: 'My_Table.Category'})
    .from('My_Table);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately the database is from a third party.

Comment: With knex using case sensitive identifiers is not really a problem. I've been using them for over half a decade, because I like to have camelCase names used in my javascript code. However it is true that if you are fine with having snake_case column names in DB result rows and ultimately snake_case attributes all the way until the rest API then it certainly is easier to use snake_case DB identifiers.  Worst thing that one can do with 
 knex/objection is to have snake_case in DB and then use mapper functions to try to have camelCase identifiers used in javascript side.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Raw Queries:

```
knex.raw('Select ID,Category IS NOT NULL AND Category IN (1, 2) AS My_Category from My_Table where ID = ?', [1]).then(function(resp) { ... });
```

Or Raw Expressions:

```
knex('My_Table')
  .select(knex.raw('ID,Category IS NOT NULL AND Category IN (1, 2) AS My_Category'))
  .where(knex.raw(1))
  .orWhere(knex.raw('ID = ?', [1]))
```

See at: 
http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Expressions
Or:
http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Queries